# How to reset MapBoxGl's line-dasharray property of a line layer?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I add a line layer in MapBoxGl with a property named line-dasharray, now I want to remove the effect of line-dasharray by `map.setPaintProperty(layerId,'line-dasharray',[1,0])`,but It still have little dash , what should I do ? And I don't want to make it by remove the layer and add it without `line-dasharray`.

Comment: Have you tried to set the paint property to an empty string, null or undefined?

Comment: Thanks a lot , null and undefined are both OK!

Comment: empty string will throw an error!

Comment: Nice, I added the solution as an answer so other people can find it more easily. Feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, the correct way to "reset" the `line-dasharray` property is this:

```
map.setPaintProperty(layerId, 'line-dasharray', null)
```

You can also use `undefined` instead of `null`, though an empty string will result in an error.